# With what I can replace "-moz-column-count" and "-webkit-column-count"?

Tags: html, css

I have like a list and I am using `-webkit-column-count` and `-moz-column-count` but when I validate my css I get warnings like `is an unknown vendor extension`? With what can I replace those?

Anyone who can provide help?

Comment: `column-count`?

Comment: The correct vendor prefix is `-moz-`.

Comment: @SuperStormer yes I am sorry I edited it.

Comment: @TJ you mean for both of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) is now well supposed according to [caniuse.com - column-count](https://caniuse.com/?search=column-count)

You can replace both vendor prefixed properties with single `column-count` declaration